# -[_SwiftValue integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000044d560 Error when using Google Mobile Vision

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift4, google-vision

I am using Google Mobile Vision in my app. I am getting a unrecognized selector lldb crash. I have narrowed down the problem to this line of code...

```
   var faceDetector = GMVDetector.init(ofType: GMVDetectorTypeFace, options: options)
```

Here is the variable `options`:

```
let options = [GMVDetectorFaceLandmarkType: GMVDetectorFaceLandmark.all, GMVDetectorFaceClassificationType: GMVDetectorFaceClassification.all, GMVDetectorFaceTrackingEnabled: false] as [String : Any]
```

Is there something wrong with `options`? I have looked at other SO posts and found that most problems originate from a dictionary.

How would I fix this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use raw value of the enums, `GMVDetectorFaceLandmark.all.rawValue` etc.

eg:

```
var faceDetector = GMVDetector(ofType: GMVDetectorTypeFace, options: [GMVDetectorFaceLandmarkType: GMVDetectorFaceLandmark.all.rawValue,
                                                                               GMVDetectorFaceClassificationType: GMVDetectorFaceClassification.all.rawValue,
                                                                               GMVDetectorFaceMinSize: 0.3,
                                                                               GMVDetectorFaceTrackingEnabled: true])
```